# python convert list of string into list intgers

Tags: python

want to convert list of string into list of integer .
It only works when I initialize list but not when the a number is converted into list.

```
a=list(raw_input("enter no :"))
print (a)
r = list(map(int, a))
print (r)
#getting error

#enter no :111
#['1', '1', '1', '\n']
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#File "C:/Users/shris/PycharmProjects/demo1/d1.py", line 4, in <module>
#r = list(map(int, a))
#ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'
#want r=[1,1,1]
```

Comment: You have a newline at the end of your string, which `int` chokes on. `list(raw_input(...).strip())` should work.

Comment: `[int(i) for i in a if i.strip()]`

Comment: Which Python version are you using, raw_input should strip the newline..?

Comment: Note that `raw_input` only works in python 2, but `map` returns a list in python 2 so the call to `list` is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

you have a newline character at the end of the string. To avoid unwanted character in you input edit your code like this:

```
a=list(raw_input("enter no :").strip())
print (a)
r = list(map(int, a))
print (r)
```

the `strip()` function is key to accomplish this. [Documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm)